# How to make an rectangle with top and bottom shadow in android using layer-list?

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-drawable, layer-list

[image: This is what i want]

I need an yellow rectangle with shadows on top and bottom as given in the image , how can i draw this using layer-list, i have no idea how to do this , especially the shadows how to achieve that shape?

Comment: use `RotateDrawable` as a bottom layer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `layer-list` seems like the best option. You'll need two rectangles, the main yellow one, and another for the shadow. You can then rotate the shadow rectangle a little to get the effect you want.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp" android:bottom="20dp" android:right="20dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-5"
            android:toDegrees="-5"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <size android:width="300dp"
                    android:height="150dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#999999"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp" android:bottom="20dp" android:right="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="300dp"
                android:height="150dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FFDD66"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If you need to make the shadow smaller, as you said in a comment, you can scale down the rectangle. You can do this either by making it smaller to begin with (the width and height) or using `<scale> ... </scale>` tags. [Here's a related SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788954/scaling-then-rotating-a-rectangle-drawable)

Comment: wow , this is cool , but the grey rectangle is visible even on the left and right side , how to remove that?

Comment: You can enclose the rotatation in `≤scale> ... </scale>` tags to make it a bit smaller. Updating answer